# Why I can't access some sites without DNS over HTTPS (DoH) enabled?

Tags: dns, ubuntu-mate

I use Ubuntu mate 18.04 LTS and I figured out how to access some sites that can't be accessed by default with Firefox or Chrome or Chromium.
Solution:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cant-access-certain-sites-even-if-they-are-ok-on-mobile-for-example/20843/2

But the question is why some domains are not resolved with an ip address by the initial DNS server and others are resolved?

I read this https://www.howtogeek.com/448629/how-dns-over-https-doh-will-boost-privacy-online/ but couldn't get an answer.